# how to replace links to versioned files of ui-router with usemin

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, angular-ui-router, grunt-usemin

Given the following file app.js

```
$stateProvider
      .state('intro', {
        url: '/intro',
        templateUrl: 'partials/intro.html',
        controller: 'IntroController as IntroCtrl'
      })
      .state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        templateUrl: 'partials/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchController as searchCtrl'
      })
      ;
```

The task is to change the templateUrl files to their revisioned counterparts which were revisioned with [grunt filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev).

I have a usemin target with grunt

```
useminPrepare: {// configuration which tasks usemin will change/run
       html: build_src + '/index.html',             
       options: {
            dest: build_dest + '',
        }
},      
usemin: {           
     html: [build_dest + '/index.html'],            
     options: {
            dirs: [build_dest + '', build_dest + '/dist']           
     }      
}
```

It is documented how to insert block comments in html and then usemin performs the revisioning and also the replacement of revisioned files.

How it is achieved for the javascript file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I continued to search after the answer of cetia

I found the solution at:
https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/235#issuecomment-33316221

```
usemin: {
            html: [build_dest + '/index.html'],
            js:[build_dest + '/**/*.js'],
            options: {
                dirs:[build_dest, build_dest + '/dist'],
                assetsDirs: [build_dest],
                patterns: {
                      // FIXME While usemin won't have full support for revved files we have to put all references manually here
                      js: [
                          [/(partials\/.*?\.html)/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved partials']
                      ]
                }
            }
        }
```

The important additions are the patterns. You need to say to usemin how to search the html links in javascript.

The assetDirs option is also important to set because usemins fileprocessor.js looks for the revved files by a map of unrevved to revved files and if the assetDirs is not set properly it won't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell usemin to replace "filerev" mappings in JS Files as well.

Try adding a "js" part in the usemin config  :

```
usemin: {           
     html: [build_dest + '/index.html'],
     js: ['js/**/*.js']       
     options: {
            dirs: [build_dest + '', build_dest + '/dist']           
     }      
}
```

Besides, you could also concat all your html files to only a big one (with grunt-html2js) using angular $cacheTemplate

Comment: I complemented the solution with additional options which i had to set

Comment: well done. Glad your bug is resolved. you can accept your own answer now :p